# How to use CSS classes with current-device

Tags: javascript, html, css, screen-orientation

I try to lock screen orientation on a portrait for mobile and iPad devices. I can use CSS snippet I found on css-tricks.com

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
```

}

This original CSS won't work because some small-size laptops could be considered as iPad or iPad won't fall under (max-width: 767px).
As well, in my code, I use the [CURRENT-DEVICE](https://github.com/matthewhudson/current-device) module to detect the type of device in the code. I want to use this module to detect mobile and tablet and apply the CSS snippet I showed above. I can detect device on JS like:

```
    if (device. Tablet()) {
      do something
    }
```

But how to trigger CSS?
On the current-devise github page, they have CONDITIONAL CSS. But I cannot understand how to use them. I googled but couldn't find more information. I hope somebody worked with this module and can help me.

Comment: You can [set CSS in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to insert a stylesheet like this:

```
if (device. Tablet()) {
    var newStyleSheet = document.createElement('style')
    document.head.appendChild(newStyleSheet);
    var sheet = newStyleSheet.sheet;
    sheet.insertRule(`
        html {
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            transform-origin: left top;
            width: 100vh;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            left: 0;
          }
    `, 0);
}
```